# Show default selected options in oiselect angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<oi-select oi-options="student.name for student in students track by student._id" 
multiple placeholder="Select student(s)" autofocus>
```

This is template.html

I have $scope.selectedStudents in directive.js. I want to make names in $scope.selectedStudents default selected options in oiselect. Thanks.

Comment: check out this http://embed.plnkr.co/LTj8vm5NgYeOKpv22MDL/

Comment: Thanks. I think it's right!

Comment: your welcome.....i think its all related to ng-model.....am i correct?